# C++ matrix multiplication different dimensions

Tags: c++, matrix, multiplication

I want to something like this:
Multiply 3x3 matrix with 3x1 matrix. I try to convert my 1 dimensional array to 2 dimensions. And I think this is ok, but later in multiplication I get errors. But I'm not sure why. Here is my code.

```
    // 20  -20  0          150
    //-20   40  -20   x     0
    // 0   -20  30         400  
    int n = 3;
double *tab_P = new double [n];

tab_P[0] = 150;
tab_P[1] = 0;
tab_P[2] = 400;


double **tab_H;
tab_H = new double* [n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    tab_H[i] = new double[n];

tab_H[0][0] = 0.2;
tab_H[0][1] = 0.15;
tab_H[0][2] = 0.1;


tab_H[1][0] = 0.15;
tab_H[1][1] = 0.15;
tab_H[1][2] = 0.1;

tab_H[2][0] = 0.1;
tab_H[2][1] = 0.1;
tab_H[2][2] = 0.1;

double **tmp_P;
tmp_P = new double *[n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    tmp_P[i] = new double [1];

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<1; j++) {
        tmp_P[i][j] = tab_P[i];
    }
}

double **result = new double * [n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    result[i] = new double [1];


int i,j,k;
int s = 0;
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<1; j++) {
        s = 0;
        for(k =0; k<n; k++)
            s += tab_H[i][k] * tmp_P[k][j];
        result[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you allocate memory for *tab_P? And again what's the error you see, Multiplication result? Or 1D array?

Comment: @theAlias He did that right at the top, it's just a one dimensional array.

Comment: I get error somewhere in loop at the end. Access violation reading location.... I think something is wrong with indexes in loop but I can't see where.

Comment: I see it now, after the post is edited

Comment: omg.. result[i][j] = s instead result[i][j]. Sorry guys!

Comment: Except for your `int s = 0;`, which should have been `double s = 0;`, i don't see any issues with the code. Can you run it on a online compiler and share the link?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not contain any memory errors (I checked it with valgrind, which is an extremely valuable tool, check it out). So, somehow you didn't copy the error into the code you posted. You should find your error when you do a character by character comparison between what you posted and your original code.

Your code has a logical bug, however: You use an `int` for the variable `s`, which you use to sum the intermediate products. Whenever you assign a value to `s`, the floating point product is rounded to an integer. This will lead to an incorrect result. Use a `double` for the variable `s`.